# Kali Linux and Raspberry Pi + phone

Tags: wifi, arm, kali

Sorry for the weird title but I seriously need to know,

If I bought a raspberry pi, a wifi dongle and an sd card and install kali linux on it, would I be able to SSH into it from my phone so I have a terminal on my phone?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Yes, although they must obviously be accessible to each other over an IP network.

Answer (score 1):

If you can download and install an SSH client for your phone then sure. But then one would wonder what exactly you could do at that point.

There are plenty of options for all major Mobile OS's.

I have used JuiceSSH and for android and it works well

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh

The SSH Client for Windows Moible:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/the-ssh-client/9wzdncrcwnwh

And surely there is something for IOS

Most of the clients work about the same, you enter your IP address of your Raspberry Pi, then enter the username and password in the required fields.

Comment: This is the opposite of what the question is.

Comment: whoops, my bad, I miss read it.

Comment: I edited to make it the appropriate answer.

Comment: At that point, with an SSH client, you can basically do anything. Your comment makes no sense

Answer (score -1):

Why not take the total gui interface??

Use this to make vnc server in rpi: sudo apt-get install realvnc-vnc-server

use raspAP available in github to create hotspot from pi.

use vnc viewer available in play store to access gui.

Comment: This isn't a answer, it could be a comment.

Comment: I cannot comment just yesterday joined this RPi community...

Comment: Then you have to follow the rules and gain more reputation so you can comment.